# Projection of vector onto $(d-1)$-dimensional unit sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

How to show that a vector $v \in  \Bbb R^d$ is projected onto $\Bbb S^{d-1}$ where $$
\Bbb P_{S^{d-1}}(v) = \frac{v}{\Vert v\Vert} \;?
$$

Comment: Obviously its length is one, provided that $v\neq0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $v \ne 0$ we have

$$\left\|v - \frac{v}{\|v\|}\right\| = \left\|v\left(1 - \frac1{\|v\|}\right)\right\| = \|v\|\left|1 - \frac1{\|v\|}\right| = |\|v\| - 1|$$

On the other hand, for any $x \in \mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ we have

$$\|v-x\| \ge |\|v\| - \|x\|| = |\|v\| - 1|$$

so $\frac{v}{\|v\|}$ is indeed the distance minimizer of $v$ to $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.